Uncaught Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: webpack/sharing/consume/default/vue/vue module-federation Vue3-in-Vue2
problem:
how can Vue3 component used in Vue2 app,with module-federation.someone need it,somewhow.
error:
Uncaught Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: webpack/sharing/consume/default/vue/vue
hope:
Vue3 component can be used in Vue2 app,with module-federation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

public/index.html:- add script tag 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" id="faviconLink" href="static/img/favicon.ico">
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/assets/remoteEntry-app3.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>

